# PhantomJS cannot find Element

Tags: angularjs, phantomjs, protractor

i have defined a testsped with orders a product from a shop. At the end of the process you will be redirected to the payment provider (paypal or else) to pay your order.
Here is the problem: The shop is based on angular but not the payment page. The test is running until i get to the payment page. Then i receive:

```
Failed: {"errorMessage":"Unable to find element with xpath '//*[@id=\"cardnumber\"]'
```

The code is this:

```
 it('submit the order', function () {
        CO4.order();
        browser.sleep(8000);
    });

    it('enters the creditcard data', function () {
        browser.driver.findElement(by.xpath('//*[@id="cardnumber"]')).sendKeys("123456789");
        browser.driver.findElement(by.xpath('//*[@id="expmonth"]')).sendKeys("12");
        browser.driver.findElement(by.xpath('//*[@id="expyear"]')).sendKeys("2050");
        browser.driver.findElement(by.xpath('//*[@id="cvm"]')).sendKeys("123");
        browser.driver.findElement(by.xpath('//*[@id="next"]')).click();
    });
```

The config is:

```
var TIMEOUT = 40000;
exports.config = {
    seleniumServerJar: '../../selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.48.2.jar',
    baseUrl: 'https://myShop/main',

    specs: [
        './UseCases/protractorSuiteCheckout.js',
    ],

    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'PhantomJS'.toLowerCase(),
        'phantomjs.binary.path': require('phantomjs').path,
        'phantomjs.cli.args': ['--ignore-ssl-errors=true', '--web-security=false'],
        'phantomjs.ghostdriver.cli.args': ['--loglevel=DEBUG']
    },

    getPageTimeout: TIMEOUT,
    allScriptsTimeout: TIMEOUT,
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        defaultTimeoutInterval: TIMEOUT,
        isVerbose: true,
        includeStackTrace: true
    },
    framework: "jasmine2",
    onPrepare: function () {
        browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
        browser.driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
            consolidateAll: true,
            filePrefix: 'xmloutput',
            savePath: 'report'
        }));
}
```

};

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Why using complicated xpath when all you are doing is a findById ?

replace

```
   browser.driver.findElement(by.xpath('//*[@id="cardnumber"]')).sendKeys("123456789");
    browser.driver.findElement(by.xpath('//*[@id="expmonth"]')).sendKeys("12");
    browser.driver.findElement(by.xpath('//*[@id="expyear"]')).sendKeys("2050");
    browser.driver.findElement(by.xpath('//*[@id="cvm"]')).sendKeys("123");
    browser.driver.findElement(by.xpath('//*[@id="next"]')).click();
```

by :

```
        browser.driver.findElement(by.id('cardnumber')).sendKeys("123456789");
        browser.driver.findElement(by.id('expmonth')).sendKeys("12");
        browser.driver.findElement(by.id('expyear')).sendKeys("2050");
        browser.driver.findElement(by.id('cvm')).sendKeys("123");
        browser.driver.findElement(by.id('next')).click();
```

See if it works better ?

Comment: same effect... any other idea?

Comment: I am also having this problem. It is almost as if PhantomJS is not loading the angular view. The tests work fine with Firefox driver.